# Angular 8 - Cannot read property 'NODE_NDEBUG' of undefined when trying serve application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular8

The error is at ../node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js from the assert-plus library where it is unable to read the 'NODE_NDEBUG' from 'process.env' as seen in the code snippet below

```
module.exports = _setExports(process.env.NODE_NDEBUG);
```

I was initially having the error https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch/issues/67 
and after following the simple instruction the error went away and then this was the next error message I got.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NODE_NDEBUG' of undefined
    at Object../node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js (assert.js:211)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object../node_modules/http-signature/lib/parser.js (parser.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object../node_modules/http-signature/lib/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object../node_modules/request/request.js (request.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object../node_modules/request/index.js (index.js:143)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
```

Here is a snapshot of my current polyfill.ts file

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
(window as any) ['global'] = window;
(window as any).process = window;
(window as any).process.browser = true;
(window as any).process.version = '';
(window as any).process.versions = {node: false};
declare var global: any;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
```

Here is a snapshot of my package.json

```
{
  "name": "staysharpadmin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jstimezonedetect": "^1.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "pushy": "^2.0.8",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "twix": "^1.2.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.3",
    "@angular/cli": "8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "os": false,
    "net": false,
    "path": false,
    "stream": false,
    "tls": false,
    "zlib": false,
    "fs": false
  }
}
```

As soon I serve the application the browser shows a white blank screen and when I inspect the page I then see the error message as indicated above. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default angular 8 already include polyfill for the application so I think you can delete everything in your polyfill

If that not working consider at this to your polyfill too

```
(window as any).global = window;
```